# UINavigation bar not getting cleared in swift3 Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uinavigationbar

I am trying to achieve a transparent navigation bar such that the background image is shown clearly. Currently i have used a base controller class where i have put a code for transparent navigation bar:

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
```

But currently i am getting the clear navigation bar only on first page. If i push and go to the second controller i can see a empty white space.
See the below images:

[First page with cleared navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gIK9.png)

[Second page with empty white space at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQTWs.png)

Why the navigation bar is not getting transparent? Any ideas?

Comment: What is the view `background color` of the second page?, And I am not able to see any difference of your attached image other than `back` button.

Comment: First you should add a navigation bar title on first screen to see if the navigation bar actually visible on first page or not ? Perhaps it is not configured and hidden on first screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Your navigation bar is `transparent`, it will show your `viewcontroller's view background color`.

I think, your second page view controller's view `background color` is `White`. Thats the reason you are getting `white color`.

**Add Top Constraint to `SuperView`, Not to `TopLayout Guide`**

[image]

Comment: i have a background image

Comment: An image of lines

Comment: What is the image constraint you added? You added to top layout right..

Comment: You have to add to `superview` not `top layout`

Comment: `TopLayout` will add your view below to `navigation bar`, So you have to add to `SuperView`

Comment: how to add to super view?

Comment: one mint, I will add it

Comment: Add a image, which will help you to add top constraint to super view

Answer (score 0):

change the view background

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

[image]

For more detail about isTranslucent read this doc
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/1624928-translucent